# Is it possible to group data by time intervals?

Tags: python

I am trying to analyze satellite telemetry data. Our satellite has 178 channels. We want to group by their updating time intervals. For example, channel 1 sending a message every 10 secs (there are 100 channels), channel 2 every 20 secs, channels 3 30 secs, channel 4 60 secs. So our channels send information according to their update time. Is it possible to sort them by time intervals?. for example group with 10 secs: all channels with 10 secs update and so on

Data:

```
channel 1:  3:25:15 (update time 10 secs)
channel 1:  3:25:25
channel 2:  3:25:35 (update time 20 secs)
channel 1:  3:25:35
channel 1:  3:25:45
channel 3:  3:25:45 (update time 30 secs)
channel 1:  3:25:55
channel 2:  3:25:55
channel 1:  3:26:05
channel 1:  3:26:15
channel 2:  3:26:15
channel 3:  3:26:15
channel 4:  3:26:15  (update time 60 secs)
```

I want a result:

```
group by 10 secs:

channel 1: 3:25:15
channel 1: 3:25:25
channel 1: 3:25:35
channel 1: 3:25:45
channel 1: 3:25:55
channel 1: 3:26:05
```

and so on for each time interval.

Note: there are 178 channels. I do not know which channels have 10 secs, 20 secs and so on. So I have to sort them by their update time.

Comment: Can you provide example data. We would need to know the format to answer the question...

Comment: @urban I wrote an example

Comment: Convert the time to seconds, round the last 10 seconds for al of them and group by that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the following might need adjustments but you should get the ideas :) Lets go step by step

First of all my data are stored in /tmp/data. I had to add another measurement for channel 4, else it is excluded (see later):

```
$ cat /tmp/data
channel 1:  3:25:15 (update time 10 secs)
channel 1:  3:25:25
channel 2:  3:25:35 (update time 20 secs)
channel 1:  3:25:35
channel 1:  3:25:45
channel 3:  3:25:45 (update time 30 secs)
channel 1:  3:25:55
channel 2:  3:25:55
channel 1:  3:26:05
channel 1:  3:26:15
channel 2:  3:26:15
channel 3:  3:26:15
channel 4:  3:26:15  (update time 60 secs)
channel 4:  3:27:15  (update time 60 secs)
```

Now, I create a loading function that will create a dictionary where the key is the channel number (int) and the value is a list of update times:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime

import re

def read_data(fpath):
    # Format: {"channel X": [update1, update2]}
    data = defaultdict(list)
    with open(fpath) as f:
        for line in f:
            parts = re.findall('[:\w]+', line)

            data[int(parts[1][:-1])].append(parts[2])

    return data


data = read_data("/tmp/data")

# Sort timestamps
for channel in data:
    data[channel].sort()
print(data)
```

This gives you (formatted output a bit to make easier to read):

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {
  1: ['3:25:15', '3:25:25', '3:25:35', '3:25:45', '3:25:55', '3:26:05', '3:26:15'], 
  2: ['3:25:35', '3:25:55', '3:26:15'], 
  3: ['3:25:45', '3:26:15'], 
  4: ['3:26:15', '3:27:15']
})
```

Finally, to the interesting code! We will loop this data and for each channel we will:

- Calculate a list of update intervals (timediff between timestamps)
- Average the above and round to int - this part might need more work in real data

Store the above in another dict where its key is the interval and the value is a list of channels that seem to have this update interval:

```
# Identify intervals
channel_interval = defaultdict(list)
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'

for channel, report_times in data.items():
    # We need at least 2 samples to determine interval - 
    # channel 4 needed another entry for this to work
    if len(report_times) < 2:
        continue

    # Collect all reports timediff for this channel
    diffs = []
    # This converts timestamp to datatime
    prev_time = datetime.strptime(report_times[0], FMT)

    for rt in report_times[1:]:
        cur_time = datetime.strptime(rt, FMT)
        diffs.append((cur_time - prev_time).seconds)
        prev_time = cur_time

    # average the report time difference - int division
    # here you might need to be smarter with real data and round up a bit
    # if needed
    interval = sum(diffs) // len(diffs)
    channel_interval[interval].append(channel)
```

And the reporting: Simply loop each channel_interval and for each channel that fall in this interval print the timestamps:

```
# report
for interval, channels in channel_interval.items():
    print("Updating every {} seconds (channels={})".format(interval, channels))
    for channel in channels:
        hdr = '\nchannel {}: '.format(channel)
        print(hdr + hdr.join(data[channel]))
        print("\n")
```

The final output is:

```
Updating every 60 seconds (channels=[4])

channel 4: 3:26:15
channel 4: 3:27:15


Updating every 10 seconds (channels=[1])

channel 1: 3:25:15
channel 1: 3:25:25
channel 1: 3:25:35
channel 1: 3:25:45
channel 1: 3:25:55
channel 1: 3:26:05
channel 1: 3:26:15


Updating every 20 seconds (channels=[2])

channel 2: 3:25:35
channel 2: 3:25:55
channel 2: 3:26:15


Updating every 30 seconds (channels=[3])

channel 3: 3:25:45
channel 3: 3:26:15
```

As I said the above might need minor changes to work with real data but should be a good start. Let me know if you have questions

---

update 1: if you want the printing to be ordered by interval you can loop

```
for channel, interval in sorted(channel_interval.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: what if my data is dataframe? I am reading it with pandas, because it is hdf5 file

Comment: @ManapShymyr I am not sure - not so good with pandas but from what I remember, the only things that changes is actually the way you iterate the data in the frame. the rest I think (including the logic) can remain the same once you have the data in {channel=>[reports]} dict

Comment: can you help if I send you data?